# Insert text to a file between before or after a certain line

Tags: file, go

Here is my function to add a message to my log file

```
func Glogger(prefix string, message string) {
    file, err := os.OpenFile("glogger.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    logger := log.New(file, prefix+" : ", log.LstdFlags)
    logger.Println(message)
}
```

This will append a new line in my log file. But I want to add my message above the gopher's head and always keep my gopher at the bottom of my file like this:

[image]

It's possible to add a new line after a log message or before a specific character like the top of the gopher's head `.:-==+++++++++++++++++++++=-:` ?

If it's not possible there is a way to count the x lines from the end of the file and start to write by setting an offset ?

Or can we delete the gopher, append the new log and then recreate the gopher ?

Comment: There's nothing Go specific here. Files are only a stream of bytes, you cannot "insert between" lines in a file; there aren't even lines, just bytes. Pick the point you want to write at and write out the data.

Comment: Why not log to an intermediate file & append the gopher in post processing?

Comment: @colm.anseo It could be nice but I need to keep the log history

Comment: Unless you have a fancy file system (I don't know of any that are this fancy) you'll have to do what you said: delete and then re-create the gopher. (This is why we usually do what @colm.anseo suggested.) Note that you'll need to drop the `O_APPEND`.

Comment: @torek how can I do to delete the x last lines to delete my gopher ?

Comment: again, files don't have "lines", you need to search for the byte offset you want to write at, and start writing from there. Overwriting or truncating the gopher will delete the gopher.

Comment: @JimB Ok thank you I'll try to do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Thanks to the commenters who shows me the way.

- I measured my gopher byte size
- I create a temp log file
- I copy the total byte size of the main log file into the temp file while  I substract the gopher byte size
- I append my log error and I draw the gopher at the end of the file

Here is my code :

```
import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

const gopherSize = 1934
const gloggerFile = "glogger.log"
const tmpFile = "tmp.log"

func Glogger(prefix string, message string) {
    // Create temp file
    tmp, err := os.Create(tmpFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer tmp.Close()

    // Check if glogger file exists open and copy until the gopher
    // to the temp file
    if _, err := os.Stat(gloggerFile); err == nil {
        glogger, err := os.Open(gloggerFile)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        defer glogger.Close()

        totalBytes, err := glogger.Stat()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        io.CopyN(tmp, glogger, totalBytes.Size()-gopherSize)
    }

    logger := log.New(tmp, prefix+" : ", log.LstdFlags)
    logger.Println(message)

    drawGoopher()
    replaceTmpFile()
}

func replaceTmpFile() {
    if _, err := os.Stat(gloggerFile); err == nil {
        if err := os.Remove(gloggerFile); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    if err := os.Rename(tmpFile, gloggerFile); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func drawGoopher() {
    file, err := os.OpenFile(tmpFile, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    file.WriteString(`

                         .:-==+++++++++++++++++++++=-:                  
                    .-+**+=-:.                      .:-+**=.                    
                 -**+:                           .:::.    .=*+:.-+++++++-       
    -+++++++++-**:   .-::::::-:              :---.   .:--:   .+%+       -**     
  -#-       :#=   .--.        .--:         -=.            --    =#. .     -#    
 -%     .. +#.   --              :=       +.               .+    .%@@@=    #-   
 #-    +@@@+    +.                 +     =. :==-.            =     #@@-    *=   
 *+    -@@=    .+.*@@@%-           :-    + #@@@@@-           =      #+    -%    
 .%-    *+     --#@@@@*@           .+    +.@@@@=-+           =       %: -*+     
   +#=.-%      .*-%@@%==           -:    :-.*%%*-           .=       -@*-       
     :=@-       :- .::            .=      :-               :=         #=        
      .%         :=.             --.=*###*-.--.          :-:          .%        
      +*           :--:      .--- :@@@@@@@@+  :----------              #-       
      %-               ::::::.  --:-*#%%%*-.--:                        +*       
     .@:                       =              .=                       -%       
     .@.                       =     :---.     =                       :@       
     :@                         :::*:  + .-+::-                        .@.      
     -@                            =   +   -.                           @.      
     :@                           .=   #   -.                           @:      
     .@.                           -::-:=::-                            @:      
      @:                                                                @:      
      #=                                                                @:      
      =*                                                                @:      
       %                                                                @:   `)

}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do that but it does the job